# helloWorld Ligthning Web Component not showing in Lightning experience

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am following Quick start: Ligtning Web Components tutorial to create first lightning Webcomponent. I deployed Lightning WebComponent helloWorld app from Visual Studio Code to the org and it is successful, see below.
[image]

But it is not showing it in the Custom here. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Can you please show how your meta.xml file looks like

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself. The issue was that *-meta.xml file isExposed was set to false, I changed it to true and then deployed again on the org.